# Como corrijo meu docker-compose.yml? expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'

Tags: docker

```
$ docker-compose up
ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 3, column 4
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in ".\docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 5
```

Parece que há um problema no meu arquivo yml. Eu li algumas outras perguntas aqui, e tentei vários esquemas e ainda não consigo fazer isso funcionar.

Onde será que está erro?

```
version: '3'
services: 
   kwan:
      image: postgres:11.5
      network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
    - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
         - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
         - POSTGRES_DB=root
    restart: unless-stopped
  backend:
       build: .
```

Veja como se encontra;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é meu arquivo Dockerfile;

```
FROM 8u131-jdk-alpine

MAINTAINER Wladimir Bandeira "tecnico100@gmail.com"

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin/

COPY dockerTest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar webapp.jar

CMD ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=docker-demo","-jar","webapp.jar"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que parece, a sua identação está errada. Os arquivos yml usam tabs ou espaços pra delimitar blocos de forma similar ao python.

`container_name`, `volumes`, `expose`,`ports`, `environment` e `restart` estão fora de `kwan`.

Tente ajustar para

```
version: '3'
services: 
   kwan:
      image: postgres:11.5
      network_mode: bridge
      container_name: postgres
      volumes:
        - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      expose:
      - 5432
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      environment:
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_DB=root
      restart: unless-stopped
  backend:
       build: .
```

Creio que isso irá resolver

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou.